# Images' URL don't want to load

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm using this code to make a image in a link in a C# MVC4 app :

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ", "../Edit", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "edit" })
```

And the CSS :

```
a.edit
        {
            background: url("~/Content/Images/edit.png") no-repeat top left;
            display: block;
}
```

But the image don't charge (404 on the img path),

So I expected the RouteConfig, but google says no.

The image is in `MyAppName/Content/Images/edit.png`

Thanks to help me

EDIT : I tried

```
url("~/Content/Images/edit.png") 
url("/Content/Images/edit.png") 
url("../Content/Images/edit.png") 
url("../../Content/Images/edit.png")
```

Comment: charge != load. You charge a battery and load a file.

Comment: edit done in the title :-) thanks

Comment: are you sure that "../Edit/" will work May not matter for the img but still, looks strange.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't chane anything. 

Now, the image loads in http://localhost:1331/Content/Images/edit.png but didn't appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image can't display if there is no place, so When I put "test" content instread of " ", the image was appearing.

The solution :

```
        a.edit {
        background: url("@Url.Content("Content/Images/edit.png")") no-repeat transparent;
        width: 14px;
        height: 14px;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
}
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `background-image` instead of just `background`:

```
a.edit {
        background-image: url("~/Content/Images/edit.png");
        backbround-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: left top;
        display: block;
}
```

Comment: @D.Stanley : it changes nothing but I appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Try without the "a" such as :

```
.edit
{
      background: url("~/Content/Images/edit.png") no-repeat top left;
      display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hello @vibouk. I tried but it isn't working. I saw the css on the item with firebug/ chrome inspector

Comment: Mais merci bien Vincent ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It is empty on the link text of  @HTML.ACTIONLINK you had given which will throw an error. Use

```
 <a href="../Edif" class="edit"></a> instead
```

Answer (score 0):

From my little experience with MVC the only way to achieve what you need is to include the CSS in the view itself then:

```
<style type="text/css">
    a.edit { background-image: url("@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/edit.png")"); }
</style>
```

The `@Url.Content` will map the given URL properly.

Comment: No... but thanks! I really oped that resolved my problem .. but no